# Shared VPC and VPC Peering mix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc-peering

On Google cloud, I have setup new three projects - dev, research and prod. So, then created an Shared VPC Host and three Service Projects as listed above. Also intend to have separate VPCs for each of these service projects (to add more security layer), hence also intend to use now VPC Peering. But confused here can we configure both Shared VPCs and VPC Peering on same set of Projects?. If so then i do not find any links on this and also is this an right thing to do?

Comment: Have a look at the https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc "Shared VPC allows an organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common VPC network, so that they can communicate with each other securely" and https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering "VPC Network Peering allows private connectivity across two VPC networks regardless of whether they belong to the same project or the same organization". So, both options are intended to connect, and mot to segregate VPCs. Why do you expect segregation with these solutions? Please provide more details about your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're looking into setting three new GCP projects (dev, research and prod). You would then have a fourth project that will act as Shared VPC Host Project, and finally you would add the 3 projects (dev, research and prod) to this Host Project and to have the chance to add more service projects to the Host project in the future.

You are wondering if Shared VPCs and VPC Peering can be used in conjunction.

As I can read on a comment on your question, these links can be useful for this [1] [2].

Moreover, I would look at this section of the second linked one [3].

As I understand you can use Shared VPCs and VPC Peering in conjunction.

Can you share more details? Could you share your thoughts on this?

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc

[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering

[3] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#shared_vpc